# Validation for minimum size file upload in PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG uploader for upload files. I want to do validation if the file size is less than 1kb. There is no properties for min File size.

**HTML**

```
<p-fileUpload multiple="true" mode="advanced" name="parseFileData[]" #fileInput
            accept=".kmz" maxFileSize="12582912" chooseLabel="Browse File"></p-fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the approach, this might help you to achieve minimum file size upload validation using p-fileUpload:

sample.component.html

```
<p-fileUpload customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="onFileUpload($event)"></p-fileUpload>
```

You can validate the file size in the component when the file gets uploaded like below:

sample.component.ts

```
onFileUpload(event) {
    let fileSize = event.files[0].size; // you will get the uploaded file size
    if (fileSize > 1000) {
      console.log("File size is Greater than 1KB");
      // logic goes here for file uploaded greater than 1KB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I was looking for templating system in primeng angular file-uplaod and come up with the basic solution you might be looking for. I'll love to share how i achieve by using it's own configuration.
**Example Scenario**

- you called API and Get configuration.
- Store this to variable called config and use in component
  [Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rweJ.png)

As you know minFileSize property since not there you can achieve my validating by uploadHandler and show error messages.

There are multiple ways to show errors. i.e. using content ng-template
[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWxiN.png)

You could found rest of validation as well with dynamic configuration. Happy Coding :)

```html
<p-fileUpload #atComp [ngClass]="internalIsValid ? '' : 'is-invalid'" class="form-control"
  *ngIf="isValidationRequired && config && !shouldReset" [customUpload]="true"
  (uploadHandler)="onUploadAttachmentHandler($event)" [auto]="true" (onRemove)="resetHandler()"
  [maxFileSize]="config?.fileMaxSizeAsBytes ? config.fileMaxSizeAsBytes : 10000"
  [fileLimit]="config?.maxFileCount ? config.maxFileCount : 1"
  [disabled]="existingAttachments.length >= (config?.maxFileCount ? config.maxFileCount : 1)"
  [multiple]="existingAttachments.length >= (config?.maxFileCount ? config.maxFileCount : 1)"
  [accept]="config?.fileExtensionsMimeType ? config.fileExtensionsMimeType : 'application/pdf'"
  [invalidFileTypeMessageSummary]="'Invalid file type'"
  [invalidFileTypeMessageDetail]="'allowed file types: ' + config?.fileExtensions"
  [invalidFileLimitMessageSummary]="'Maximum number of files exceeded'"
  [invalidFileSizeMessageDetail]="'maximum upload size is ' + config?.fileMaxSizeAsMB + 'MB'">
  <ng-template pTemplate="content">
    <div class="ui-fileupload-row" *ngFor="let file of existingAttachments">
      <div class="p-fileupload-row">
        <div><img [src]="'/assets/icons/file-types/' + file?.fileExtensions ? file?.fileExtensions : 'file' + '.png'"
            alt="Attachment" /></div>
        <a class="p-fileupload-filename file-link" (click)="downloadAttachment(file)">{{file.fullName}}</a>
        <div>110 B</div>
        <div>
          <button type="button" icon="pi pi-times" pbutton="" class="p-element p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
            ng-reflect-icon="pi pi-times" (click)="deleteAttachment($event, file)"><span
              class="p-button-icon pi pi-times" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="p-button-label">&nbsp;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-fileUpload>
```

Answer (score -1):

`(onBeforeUpload) -> event.formData: FormData object. -> Callback to invoke before file upload is initialized.`
The doc says like this. You can check the file size from the FormData, before uploading it.